# My Mysql's function always returns true

Tags: mysql

Im a newbie with mysql. I did not find an answer that corresponds to my case.
I wrote a **function that should returns *false* when "apseudo" is found more than 5 times in the TABLE "member_answer".**
The problem is that this function always return True. Can you help me please?

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION noMaxTryValideMail(theMail VARCHAR(150)) RETURNS BOOLEAN

    BEGIN 

            /*This function returns True when we have at most 5 times "a pseudo"    in member_answer        */
      DECLARE varEmail VARCHAR(150);
      DECLARE varPseudo VARCHAR(35);

      DECLARE nbTry SMALLINT; 
      DECLARE canContinueValidMail BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE;

      SET varEmail := theMail;
      SET varPseudo := NULL;

      SELECT pseudo INTO varPseudo FROM inscription_member WHERE email_1 = varEmail;
      SELECT COUNT(pseudo) INTO nbTry FROM member_answer WHERE pseudo =@varPseudo; 

      IF nbTry >0 AND nbTry <6 THEN 
        SET canContinueValidMail := TRUE;
        RETURN canContinueValidMail;


      ELSE

          SET canContinueValidMail:= FALSE;
          RETURN canContinueValidMail;

      END IF ;

    END
```

Comment: `varPseudo` and `@varPseudo` are not the same thing.

Comment: Thank to you i did'nt noticed this. But it seem's not working even when i make the correction. Perhaps it's an overkill procedure like e4c5 said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stored procedure seems way overkill for this one. Unless i've misunderstood your question, an inner join like this can replace your stored procedure. Just check the return count in your application code usually a one liner.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inscription_member i INNER JOIN
member_answer m on m.pseudo = i.pseudo
 WHERE email_1 = ?
```

Comment: Thank you very much, e4c5 . I use your statement and it is working good. That mean, overkill procedure may not work even if the algorithm seems correct?

Comment: I think Gordon's comment addresses the specifc issue with your SP. But usually we dont' write SPs for simple tasks and leave them for things that can't be done with simple queries. Even then, lots of people argue that you are better of implementing such complex things in your application logic rather than as an SP (I don't always agree with that)

Comment: I take note of those who are more experienced, so It would be very good if I could make a functional SP as I tried.
 It would  help me to understand in detail where I go (with my code), but I prefer then that my code is optimized and easily understandable,
If it keeps on less line, as you helped me do it.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: glad to have been of help. I think you are a good learner. all the best with your project.

Answer (score 0):

With your help, my code works, by becoming :

```
  CREATE FUNCTION maxTryValideMail2(theMail VARCHAR(150)) RETURNS BOOLEAN
        BEGIN 
            DECLARE nbtry SMALLINT;

            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nbTry FROM inscription_member i INNER JOIN
            member_answer m on m.pseudo = i.pseudo
            WHERE email_1 = theMail ;

            return nbTry > 5;

        END
```

Thank you.